# What is the different between NCHAR type and binary type in TDengine SQL?

Tags: tdengine

The documentation of TDengine only notes:

> In TDengine, the following 10 data types can be used in data model of
> an ordinary table, which are : timestamp, int, bigint, float, double,
> binary, smallint, tinyint, bool, nchar

However, I found there is a 'binary' type in the example at the beginning of TAOS SQL chapter, which also show be used with fixed length:

```
Binary(8) or Nchar(8)
```

So what is the different between nchar and binary type?

Answer (score 1):

All the data types are documented in [TAOS SQL, section Data Types](https://www.taosdata.com/en/documentation/taos-sql#data-type):

#### BINARY

> Used to record ASCII strings. Theoretically, the maximum length can be
> 16,374 bytes, but since each row of data can be up to 16K bytes, the
> actual limit is generally smaller than the theoretical value. Binary
> only supports string input, and single quotation marks are used at
> both ends of the string, otherwise all English will be automatically
> converted to lowercase. When using, the size must be specified. For
> example, binary (20) defines a string with a maximum length of 20
> characters, and each character occupies 1 byte of storage space. In
> this case, if the user string exceeds 20 bytes, an error will be
> reported. For single quotation marks in strings, they can be
> represented by escape character backslash plus single quotation marks,
> that is\ '.

#### NCHAR

> Used to record non-ASCII strings, such as Chinese characters. Each
> nchar character takes up 4 bytes of storage space. Single quotation
> marks are used at both ends of the string, and escape characters are
> required for single quotation marks in the string, that is \’. When
> nchar is used, the string size must be specified. A column of type
> nchar (10) indicates that the string of this column stores up to 10
> nchar characters, which will take up 40 bytes of space. If the length
> of the user string exceeds the declared length, an error will be
> reported.

In other words, BINARY is a bit of a misnomer, as it seems to be a basic ASCII character type, and uses 1 byte per character. On the other hand, NCHAR stores Unicode characters, and uses 4 bytes per character.